# OpenCL Kernel performance is very bad. Why my code is better without OpenCL?

Tags: c++, performance, kernel, opencl, simulation

I'm writing an Ant-Simulation.
The Kernel Performance is very bad. In comparsion to standard c++ solution it has a big performance disadvantage.

I dont understand why. The operations in the kernel are mostly without control structures (like if/else).

Kernels:

https://github.com/Furtano/BA-Code-fuer-Mac/blob/master/BA/Ant.cl

https://github.com/Furtano/BA-Code-fuer-Mac/blob/master/BA/Pheromon.cl

I made a benchmark, and the OpenCL Kernel Performance is very bad.
(Left Axis: Execution time in ms, Bottom Axis: number of simulated Ants)
[image: http://abload.de/img/kernel0uu3z.png]

Can you give me advice?

You can find the hole code in the git repo, if you are interested (the OpenCL stuff is happening here: https://github.com/Furtano/BA-Code-fuer-Mac/blob/master/BA/clInitFunctions.cpp).

Thanks :)

Comment: "The operations in the kernel are mostly without control structures (like if/else)." I see a good number of control structures, like `if`, `for`, etc. As I understand things, each instance of execution must be executing the same instruction (a la SIMD/SIMT). This means that if one instance is in the for-loop, but all the other instances took the false branch of the if and aren't in the for-loop, they must wait for it so they can all stay on the same instruction.

Comment: Are you sure the selected platform is your GPU?  Maybe add some of the console output to your question.

Comment: yes i think so (not sure) look here: https://github.com/Furtano/BA-Code-fuer-Mac/blob/master/BA/clInitFunctions.cpp#L328

Comment: @Furtano In the code that chooses the platform, you have a comment stating "simply choose the first available platform", that might or might not be a GPU.  Does your code output anything to the console?

Comment: @AnthonyVallée-Dubois there is no output

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of if/else, can't you write it in a different way? 
Don't follow the if/else path, since you will never reach anywhere.
You need to make the GPU will only execute useful instructions. Not millions of if/else.

It may be better to keep track and execute only the ants that are live in the grid. You better keep track of them and move them around. Having stored their coordinates.
You will obviously need as well a map with the ant positions and status, so you will need a multi kernel system.

In addition, you have a los of non-useful memory transfers, starting from using int variables for single boolean storage. This can lead to 90% of non useful transfer that can bottleneck the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Your OpenCL kernels have ifs. Current GPUs aren't supposed to do that. AFAIK an AMD GPU has n groups of 64 cores that have the same instruction pointer (they are executing the exact same part of the exact same statement). Ifs are implemented by stopping some of the cores, executing the true branch, stopping the others and executing the false branch. Imagine this with nested ifs or loops.

Comment: So i removed the ifs from one kernel and only executed this one kernel. The Performance is still bad (no gain :().

Comment: loops are also very slow

Comment: i have no loops and ifs in kernel 1. no performance gain (changed version not on github)